# PHP Category Reverse Traversal Algorithm

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, traversal

I'm trying to optimize an e-commerce category system with unlimited category depth (barring system memory limitations). I retrieve all the categories at once and order them as a multi-dimensional array that *roughly* looks like:

```
[array] (
  [0] (
    'CategoryId' => 1,
    'ParentCategoryId' => 0,
    'Title' => 'Category A',
    'SubCategories' => [array] (
      [0] (
        'CategoryId' => 2,
        'ParentCategoryId' => 1,
        'Title' => 'Category B',
        'SubCategories' => [array] (
          [0] (
            'CategoryId' => 3,
            'ParentCategoryId' => 2,
            'Title' => 'Category C'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Each item in the array is actually an object, but for simplicity I wrote it out kind of like an array format.

I'm able to traverse my tree downwards using this function:

```
/**
* Find Branch using Recursive search by Object Key
* @param String     Needle
* @param Array      Haystack
* @return Array
*/
public static function findBranchByKey($key, $needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $item) 
    {
        if ( $item->$key == $needle || ( is_object($item) && $item = self::findBranchByKey($key, $needle, $item->SubCategories)) ) 
        {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This finds the object with a matching key and returns it (which may contain more subcategories).

My issue is figuring out how to traverse the other direction. For example, using the data above, let's say I am displaying "Category C" and want to create bread crumbs of it's parents. I can't think of a good way to take my **tree** array, jump to a specific subcategory, then iterate upwards to get each parent. A resulting array from something like this could be like this so it's easy to spit them out as bread crumbs:

```
 array( 'Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C' )
```

I could probably do this using SQL in my database but I'd like to retrieve the tree once, cache it, and perform traversal on that object whenever I need to rather than making tons of queries.

TL;DR; How can I traverse upwards in a multidimensional array of categories?

Comment: Nodes in a node tree (that's what you have here) should have a **reference to their parent**, as well as a reference to all their children.

Comment: Each of your categories seems to have a `ParentCategoryId`, I suppose you would use that. :I

Comment: As in something other than the `ParentCategoryId` value?

Comment: @cillosis the `ParentCategoryId` is an integer, not a reference. You could have a second array that is a flat array of `categoryId => node`. That would allow you to look up the node reference based on `categoryId` or `parentCategoryId` instead of having to stash a reference (which will lead to recursion issues if you try to print it out with `print_r` for example).

Comment: You'd build the lookup table while ordering the elements. You could just as easily set the reference to the parent node, but as I said, that will get you in trouble with certain PHP functions like `print_r`.

Comment: @crush, That's an interesting idea. Let me see what I can do with that concept.

Comment: @crush Just an FYI, print_r and var_dump are smart enough to not get caught in a recursion loop. They will just print `*RECURSION*` when it detects a loop. [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fp6epk)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That's true. I forgot they do that - don't work in PHP as much these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by recursion.

Let's say, this function should work:

```
function getPath($id, $tree, &$path = array()) {
    foreach ($tree as $item) {
        if ($item['CategoryId'] == $id) {           
            array_push($path, $item['CategoryId']);
            return $path;
        }
        if (!empty($item['SubCategories'])) {
            array_push($path, $item['CategoryId']);
            if (getPath($id, $item['SubCategories'], $path) === false) {
                array_pop($path);
            } else {
                return $path;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'CategoryId' => 10,
        'ParentCategoryId' => 0,
        'SubCategories' => array(
            array(
                'CategoryId' => 12,
                'ParentCategoryId' => 1,
                'SubCategories' => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'CategoryId' => 1,
        'ParentCategoryId' => 0,
        'SubCategories' => array(
            array(
                'CategoryId' => 2,
                'ParentCategoryId' => 1,
                'SubCategories' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'CategoryId' => 3,
                'ParentCategoryId' => 1,
                'SubCategories' => array()
            ),
                        array(
                'CategoryId' => 4,
                'ParentCategoryId' => 1,
                'SubCategories' => array(
                    array(
                        'CategoryId' => 5,
                        'ParentCategoryId' => 4,
                        'SubCategories' => array()
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$result = getPath(5, $data);
print_r($result);
```

will result in:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 )
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely Brilliant! For some reason I couldn't get my head around a good way to do the recursion on this. I really need to package up this category stuff into a nice reusable class and share it. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear, @cillosis :)